# Mirroring Traffic with Nginx

Tags: nginx, traffic

I need to duplicate/mirror the traffic comming to my server/resource.

I mean, I have server A and B and N (nginx) as webserver.

All the traffic comming to N/resource --> redirect to both A and B

Is it possible?

Comment: You probably don't want to do this. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: I really need it to do it

Comment: I have a use case. I have a client pushing data to my servers that our production infrastructure uses. I need the exact same data pushed to my dev servers to further development. The client is only capable of sending the data to 1 endpoint. Don't ask why, I don't know.

Comment: Oh I need to duplicate traffic, I mean the traficc will process by A, but B will recevid make offline process

Comment: You want the HTTP-requests to be duplicated and the response of one machine to be discarded?

Comment: yes, that rigth

Comment: I found another version of this question with an answer that helped me: http://serverfault.com/a/515531/175380 Basically, you set the location to be mirrored up in a `post_action` directive. This will run after the request has been satisfied by the production machine.

Answer (score 18):

Nginx now has an http mirror module.  Documentation is at https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html

Example configuration from the documentation:

```
location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}

location /mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://test_backend$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can use a mirror even if one of the host is down, I have a use case for that.

Comment: I presume `/mirror` would be passed to `test_backend`, for example, http://example.com/mirror right?

Answer (score 3):

Here is new feature from nginx (1.13.4):
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html#mirror

> The ngx_http_mirror_module module (1.13.4) implements mirroring of an original request by creating background mirror subrequests. Responses to mirror subrequests are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Based on their [README](https://github.com/buger/gor/blob/master/README.md) It looks that GOR could help you solving your problem.

I never used it before, just stumbled upon it this week, so good luck!

Comment: Hey on using GOR it just acknowledges with a http 200. So if he has a response object or validation he wants done with what the client is sending him I dont think this will work for him.

As far as I can tell, and I'm new to Gor, you can't pass on the result object from one of your output segments.

Comment: We are testing GOR right now and we have a couple of problems. It interprets headers like: Location: //newpath generating requests like GET //newpath. Redirects loose original headers (including host useragent etc.) We are migrating to another tool.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot mirror requests with NGINX but the request is available as a variable.  You could use Lua scripting to send that variable to a third party server as a sub request though. 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request

Comment: Would you have an example of this? I'm looking for exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

After digging and digging I found a solution.
You can see it here [Copy and deliver a request to another nginx server for real traffic testing](https://serverfault.com/a/515531/276437) by @scari

Just thought I should mention it here to ease the search for other people.
On my setup I didn't use uwsgi - instead I wanted to duplicate every incoming request to an additional servers (in addition to the backbones servers that was load balanced already.

Hope it will help,
Liron