# Only log rate limit violations in nginx

Tags: nginx

Before enforcing per IP rate limits I wonder if there is a mode to only log violations without actually blocking clients. Therefore I could easilly check after some time that those parameters were correct.
Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use undocumented `post_action` option to [mirror traffic](https://serverfault.com/a/515531/94415) to other nginx instance with rate limiting, and check it's logs.

Or you can lust analyze logs from your server.