# Nginx Reverse Proxy HTTP Interceptor

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to mirror the HTTP Traffic to a separate server to perform independent process (no response needed) while at the same time serving the original requests?

Preferably I would like to do it using built in directives from nginx. 
[Something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znbpx.png)

Comment: Are you just trying to dump the traffic or are you actually intending to send it to an HTTP server etc?

Comment: Send it to an HTTP server

Comment: Does it need to be at the same time? You could monitor the log, which are close to real time, or batch them later.

Comment: Preferably yes. But I think monitoring the log will also suffice. Thanks for the suggestion. @Tim

Answer (score 0):

It [may be possible in Nginx with post_action](https://serverfault.com/questions/515284/copy-and-deliver-a-request-to-another-nginx-server-for-real-traffic-testing/515531#515531) (found using Google search). You could also consider using [GOR](https://github.com/buger/gor/blob/master/README.md) to do this.

Some kind of log file processing could be simpler, either near realtime or batch.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible. HTTP requires responses both ways, you can't mirror it. If you want to you could duplicate the payloads of the HTTP messages by writing them to a queue and then copying the queue and sending it to multiple places. This is what ActiveMQ/RabbitMQ is all about.

But not just with HTTP itself.

Comment: I don't think they want two web servers to participate, I think they just want another to get access to the requests. A voyeuristic web server. It doesn't seem particularly complex, though it's unusual so it may require writing code if it has to be done live.

Comment: He says he wants to send it to a 2nd HTTP server in his remark.

Comment: I do want to send it to an HTTP server but I dont need the response from the second sever. Tim may have got the idea of what I intended to do. I will also try to take into account @TheFiddlerWins answer by studying the suggested technology.

Comment: Easy enough to mirror incoming tcp traffic on port 80, assuming it's not encrypted. Look at netcat ("nc") .