# Traffic mirroring with nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, mirroring

Simply put using Nginx I am trying to mirror all the traffic hitting one of our apps, app A to a newly deployed test app. I know that there is the mirror module but I was wondering if there is any other way to implement this? Even if it's not thru Nginx.

Cheers,

Comment: there is a directive called post_action, but I am not sure if it will stop any response from the test app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mirroring Traffic with Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/513859/mirroring-traffic-with-nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up upgrading nginx as the post_action directive didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your physical hardware or maybe even the cloud service.

You could also do it with your linux server ( see example [here](https://medium.com/swlh/traffic-mirroring-with-linux-tc-df4d36116119) ).

I'm guessing running it on the cloud will cost money, while running it on the VM will demand some CPU - but I never tried to do that.